# Select All Feature in v-select not save all the items

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to add a select all button to the v-select component of vuetify. I am able to select all the options with the button but when I click on save it doesn't save all the items. But if I manually choose all the opens one by one and then click on save then all the items from the dropdown are saved. Please help me find the problem.

```
<template>
 <v-select
  :items="documents"
  v-model="user.versions"
  :closeOnSelect="true"
  multiple
  attach
  auto
  item-text='name'
  item-value='id'>
 </v-select>
 <v-btn class="red-button" @click='selectAll'>Select</v-btn>
 <v-btn class="red-save-btn" @click='submitDocuments'><i class="material-icons edit">save</i> Save</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  props: ['user'],
  data: function () {
      return {
       documents: [],
       versions: []
      }
  },
  methods: {
   selectAll (){
    this.user.versions = [...this.documents]
    },
   submitDocuments() {
        var that = this;
        this.$axios.put(`/my_account/users/${this.user.id}.json`, {user: this.user})
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit a prop directly, which should give you following warning:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.

To work with v-model you can use a computed setter/getter:

```
computed : {
  _user : {
     get () {
        return this.user
     },
     set (val) {
        this.$emit('change', val)
     }
   }
}
```

and direct the v-model on your v-select to the computed property `<v-select v-model="_user.versions">`

working example https://codepen.io/ellisdod/pen/jOPeRyr?editable=true&editors=101